# python selenium webscraping "NoSuchElementException" not recognized

Tags: python, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sometimes on a page I'll be looking for an element which may or may not be there. I wanted to try/catch this case with a `NoSuchElementException`, which selenium was throwing when certain HTML elements didn't exist. Original exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#one"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/6q/7xcjtgyj32nfc2yp_y5tr9pm0000gn/T/tmp63Mz2a/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8899)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement (file:///var/folders/6q/7xcjtgyj32nfc2yp_y5tr9pm0000gn/T/tmp63Mz2a/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8911)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/6q/7xcjtgyj32nfc2yp_y5tr9pm0000gn/T/tmp63Mz2a/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10840)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/6q/7xcjtgyj32nfc2yp_y5tr9pm0000gn/T/tmp63Mz2a/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10845)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/6q/7xcjtgyj32nfc2yp_y5tr9pm0000gn/T/tmp63Mz2a/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10787)
```

Ironically, it won't let me catch this exception which it was throwing before? Code here:

```
elt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.information')
try:
    dat1 = elt.find_element_by_css_selector('#one').text
    dat2 = elt.find_elements_by_css_selector('#two')[1].text
    text = dat1 + dat2
except NoSuchElementException:
    text = elt.find_element_by_css_selector('#all').text
    item.set_description(text)
```

Error here:

```
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
```

Googling/documentation came up with nothing...and it strikes me as strange that selenium is fine throwing an exception but can't catch it.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You need to import the exception first

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

and then you can reference it

```
except NoSuchElementException:
    # handle the element not existing
```

If you would like to give details of the exception in your output then you can use:

```
except NoSuchElementException as exc:
    print(exc) # and/or other actions to recover
```

Comment: Is it best to import just the exceptions you're going to potentially utilize or import the entire exceptions class?

Comment: Personally I feel is that it is normally a great idea to keep a namespace so `import selenium.common.exceptions as selexcept` then using `selexcept.NoSuchElementException` flags to the reader, _possibly yourself later_ that it is a package specific exception.

Comment: wow kind of had a feeling i had to do this, but thought they must include the exception by default xD. tytyty

Comment: ive imported the exception, but it still only logs `Message: Unable to locate element: ...` should it not explicitly mention `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: @oldboy I have updated the answer to show how to get details of the specific exception.

Comment: hm... for some reason my scripts never seem to throw `NoSuchElementException` exceptions anymore, even if i import the exception. is this a caveat of using explicit waits (e.g. `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath)))`)? iirc, i was reading the documentation the other day and it did say that `EC` should be throwing the `NoSuchElementException` exception

Comment: @oldboy - using wait.until will simply not do anything until it gets such an element (potentially forever) or until a time out of the wait. In the event of a timeout you might well get a Time Out exception rather than a No Such Element one I am no10  100% sure - of course with no timeout you simply will never execute the code that is waiting for the element if none is ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You sould use `from selenium.common.exceptions import *` and then write `except NoSuchElementException`

Comment: No please. just import what you need.

Comment: It's not a good practice to import all (*). Just select only those which you actually require

Comment: Why just "import selenium.common.exceptions"  not eworking? Interesting..

Comment: @FuadAk If you use `import selenium.common.exceptions` then you need to give the fully qualified name `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` of course you could use `import selenium.common.exceptions as sex` then you can use `sex.NoSuchElementException` etc :-)