# How to fix this python-selenium try-except block?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a python class to handle some basic selenium stuff. One of the methods is a wrapper to check if some element is present on the page:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException

...

def check_element(self, by, element):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by, element)  
        return True
    except TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

I call this method with something like this:

```
self._base.check_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon"]))
```

But when running the code I get an unexpected error:

```
  ...
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Jenkins/selenium-tests/selenium_tests/tools/basicsuite.py", line 277, in check_element
    self.driver.find_element(by, element)
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Jenkins/venv_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Jenkins/venv_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Jenkins/venv_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]
```

Why hasn't this exception been caught by the `try-except` block above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium webscraping "NoSuchElementException" not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200497/python-selenium-webscraping-nosuchelementexception-not-recognized)

Comment: `except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):`

Comment: You don't use ExplicitWait in your function... so why do you expect to get `TimeoutException`?

Comment: How can **`((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon"]))`** return **`Unable to locate element: //*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]`**

Answer (score 0):

Straigh from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
def check_element(self, by, element):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by, element)  
        return True
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
        return False
```