# Application is launched and closed suddenly, Then Pycharm throws element not found exception

Tags: python, android, pycharm, appium

**PyCharm Code:**

```
from appium import webdriver



desired_caps = {}

desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'

desired_caps['automationName'] = 'UiAutomator2'

desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '10'

desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'AppiumEmulator'

desired_caps['app'] = ('G:\\Appium\\KickStartAppium\\Android_Demo_App.apk')

desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher'

desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.NexusLauncherActivity'

desired_caps['udid'] = 'emulator-5554'





driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)



driver.implicitly_wait(10)

ClickEle = driver.find_element_by_id("com.code2lead.kwad:id/EnterValue")

ClickEle.click()
```

**PyCharm Error:**

```
"C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Nandha Kumar/PycharmProjects/AppiumLaunchApp/KickStartApp.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Nandha Kumar/PycharmProjects/AppiumLaunchApp/KickStartApp.py", line 19, in <module>

    ClickEle = driver.find_element_by_id("com.code2lead.kwad:id/EnterValue")

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id

    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 279, in find_element

    return self.execute(RemoteCommand.FIND_ELEMENT, {

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 31, in check_response

    raise wde

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 26, in check_response

    super().check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Nandha Kumar\PycharmProjects\AppiumLaunchApp\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Selenium didn't find your specified element here:

```
ClickEle = driver.find_element_by_id("com.code2lead.kwad:id/EnterValue")
```

selenium then always throws an exception and ends the program. If you want the code to go on you have to import the NoSuchElementException from selenium and do it like this:
Import the Exception first:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

and then you can reference it

```
except NoSuchElementException:
    # handle the element not existing
```

my answer is just copied from this kind gentlemans answer (1st answer): [python selenium webscraping "NoSuchElementException" not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200497/python-selenium-webscraping-nosuchelementexception-not-recognized)

Comment: Hi Luis, Thanks for the support, Actually I entered the wrong App Package and Activity values! It worked...