# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (FIndElement)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

i try to find an Element by Text. If i want to click the Element i'll get the following Error:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Any Idea how to fix that?

Here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as keyController
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
mouse = Controller()
keyboard = keyController()




driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Ticket = False
link = 'https://www.fansale.de/fansale/tickets/hard-heavy/rammstein/526/12055317'
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(5)

#Cookies
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))
mouse.position = (1117, 824)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT('Reihe 28')).click()
```

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFlKy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error in the last row. This happens because you are trying to call `By.LINK_TEXT` filter that cannot be called. You need to separate your filter `By.LINK_TEXT` and the value `'Reihe 28'` into two different parameters.

Replace your last string to this:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value='Reihe 28').click()
```

Comment: now i get the following error "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Reihe"}"

the class is looking like this:
<span class="EventEntryRow OfferEntry-SeatDescription visible-md" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Reihe 10 | Platz 6 | Ostkurve 35.1</span>

How can i find an Element by "break-word"

Comment: This error is the base error, that is raised all the time, when the page you are crawling doesn't have an element you are trying to find. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200889/15837436) is the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Reihe 20')]").click()
```

Grab the first span that contains that text.